# Ubuntu Server: Apache2 seems to attach .php to URI

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I'm using the php library tonic for web services. My resource is as example at

```
base-uri/myResource
```

Now if a file myResource.php exists in that directory, the url mod_rewrite gets to see is

```
base-uri/myResource.php
```

which then fails the rewrite conditions and my application breaks (app works on apache on windows)

If I rename myResource.php to my myResourceClass.php (or anything else), it works.

So it seem that apache or one if its modules assumes that with base-uri/myResource I want to call base-uri/myResource.php but only if myResource.php exists.

Is this a general issue or can I somewhere configure this to not happen?

thanks!

EDIT:

see

[How to set up a basic mod_rewrite?](https://serverfault.com/questions/359290/how-to-set-up-a-basic-mod-rewrite)

The answer contains the same observation!

ANSWER:

The issue is the default Apache configuration on Ubuntu:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

MultiViews is changing request_uri from myResource to myResource.php.

Solutions:

- disable MultiViews in .htaccess: Options -MultiViews
- remove MultiViews from default config
- rename the file as example to myResourceClass

I chose last option because that should work regardless of configuration and I only have 3 such files so the change took about 30 secs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the default Apache configuration on Ubuntu:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

MultiViews is changing request_uri from myResource to myResource.php.

Solutions:

- disable MultiViews in .htaccess: Options -MultiViews
- remove MultiViews from default config
- rename the file as example to myResourceClass

I chose last option because that should work regardless of configuration and I only have 3 such files so the change took about 30 secs...

Answer (score 0):

There's a very high chance that there's a `.htaccess` file in the folder that checks if something with `.php` exists as a file, and if so, add the `.php` extention.

My advice: check for a `.htaccess` file in the folder. If there's one, and my advice was not enough, then please add to your question so we can go further.

Comment: Yes. Just edited my question at the same time you responded. The issue is Apache Option "MultiViews".

Comment: So don't put your answer in the question :)  Just answer yourself and check it as valid in 24 hours =)

Comment: With my reputation you have to wait 8 h before you can even add an answer and then wait another 24 h to accept it. Thats why i did it this way...